# Change Data Frame to Table

Tags: r

I have a `DF` that I'm trying to make into a table to make the Pareto chart. This `DF` has two columns (`KEY AND PRICE`) This is my query:

```
library (qcc)

row.names (DF) <- DF$KEY #### row name is the same as my key. It is a condition for making the chart.
pareto.chart (DF, cumperc = seq (0,100, by = 5)) ### create graph
```

When I try to create the graph I get the message: `Error in as.table.default (data): cannot coerce to a table`

I tried using `as.table (as.matrix (DF))`, but still as Data.Frame.

How do I turn my DF into a table?

Answer (score 2):

The input `pareto.chart` takes is a named vector or named number. 
Here is an example using a sample `DF`:

```
llibrary (qcc)
DF <- data.frame(KEY=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                 PRICE = c(7, 5, 10, 15, 20, 100, 7, 100, 100, 80))
# create a vector of PRICE
price <- DF$PRICE
# assign key as name to price
names(price) <- DF$KEY

# plot using price
pareto.chart (price, cumperc = seq (0,100, by = 5), main="Example") ### create graph
```

## Output

[image: pareto_chart_example]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass a named vector to the `pareto.chart` function:

```
library(qcc)

df <- data.frame(key = c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"),
                 price = c(22, 34, 53, 14),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_vec <- df$price # Create a vector of the prices

names(data_vec) <- df$key # Name the vector elements by the 'key' variable in the data frame

pareto.chart(data_vec, ylab = "Price")
```